# DATENAME(MONTH,GETADATE()) is returning numeric value of the month as '09'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, localization

When I run the following query [SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())], ideally speaking it should return value as 'September' but its returning value as '09'. I am running this query on MS SQL Server 2005. Is there anything I need to configure with MS SQL Server 2005?

Please find the details of the SQL Server 2005

```
Component Name                                Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio        9.00.1399.00
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      2005.090.1399.00
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)       2000.086.3959.00 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710)
Microsoft MSXML                               2.6 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                   6.0.3790.3959
Microsoft .NET Framework                      2.0.50727.42
Operating System                              5.2.3790
```

Comment: What version is your server itself? This is just the client? Normally the version number is displayed in the Object Explorer window next to the name of the server you're connected to. For example: MyDBServerName (SQL Server 9.0.3042 - userId).

Comment: The question has been answered, but Praful is not a user anymore, it should be marked as answered

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT @@LANGUAGE -> gives an Asian one?

SET LANGUAGE Japanese
SELECT DATENAME (month, GETDATE())

SET LANGUAGE us_english
SELECT DATENAME (month, GETDATE())
```

[DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395(SQL.90).aspx) depends on language, so need to change server default or your login default language...

Thank you and sayonara...

Comment: Hey thanks for the post, i tried out the above mentioned it works.The language was set to "simplified chinese" which does not support the month names when I set it to us_english it works fine.
For more lnaguage help refer output of -- EXEC sp_helplanguage;--

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm, I get "September", SqlServer 2005 9.00.3402.

Comment: Ditto for me. I have 9.0.3073.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()); returns September for me. I just tried it in SQL 2005 and 2008. Where are you executing this query? That may help as to why this is happening to you.

Comment: The SQL Server 2005 is installed on Windows 2003 server.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of would be collation causing that, but I can't find any specific examples of a collation that would do that. The other possibility could be the language which also sets date format. I'm a bit mystified, but these are places to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

select name ,alias, dateformat
from syslanguages
  where langid =
   (select value from master..sysconfigures where comment = 'default language')

To see what language the system thinks it's using. SqlServer changes its date format based on that.