# Sql 2008 r2 - Datename

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

This is copied ditto from example given in [Sql2008 R2 doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) - *Syntax: `DATENAME (datepart ,date )`*

```
SELECT DATENAME(datepart,'2007-10-30 12:15:32.1234567 +05:10')
```

And it throws

```
Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
'datepart' is not a recognized datename option.
```

What is wrong here ? Where is Bill...

Comment: It must be a massive typo(:- here is the rest..Examples
The following example returns the date parts for the specified date.

SELECT DATENAME(datepart,'2007-10-30 12:15:32.1234567 +05:10') 

Here is the result set. 

datepart  Return value  
year, yyyy, yy 
 2007
 
quarter, qq, q 
 4
 
month, mm, m 
 October
 
dayofyear, dy, y 
 303
 
day, dd, d 
 30
 
week, wk, ww 
 44
 
weekday, dw 
 Tuesday
 
hour, hh 
 12
 
minute, n 
 15
 
second, ss, s 
 32
 
millisecond, ms 
 123
 
microsecond, mcs 
 123456
 
nanosecond, ns 
 123456700
 
TZoffset, tz 
 310
 

See

Comment: and is from here  ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v10/MS.SQLSVR.v10.en/s10de_6tsql/html/11855b56-c554-495d-aad4-ba446990153b.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify what part of the date you want in the place of datepart parameter.
Check this link:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

So in case you need year part of the date it would be:

```
SELECT DATENAME(year,'2007-10-30 12:15:32.1234567 +05:10')
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is wrong here?

This is not supposed to be copied and run.

You should substitute `datepart` with any of the valid options given under the example your copied (`year`, `quarter`, `month` etc).

> Where is Bill...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates%27_house

Answer (score 1):

My local BOL with the same link is quite clear what a "datepart" is

[image: MSDN screenshot]

[Note: some DATENAME calls return numbers for Far Eastern languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497952/datenamemonth-getadate-is-returning-numeric-value-of-the-month-as-09/1500018#1500018)

Answer (score 0):

Also note that DATENAME will return data as a varchar datatype. Use DATEPART function which retunrs data as integer datatype

```
SELECT DATEPART(year,'2007-10-30 12:15:32.1234567 +05:10')
```