# MS SQL select a datetime by month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you select a datetime column by month?

```
TABLE A
TITLE   MY_DATETIME   
blah    2011-03-26 05:44:43.213

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE A
WHERE MY_DATETIME = "August"
```

Comment: `WHERE month(MY_DATETIME) = 8`

Comment: @MGA: There is in SQL Server 2008. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx

Comment: @MGA: really? Been there forever http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933239(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE A
WHERE DATEPART(month, MY_DATETIME) = 8
```

Or, less reliably [based on language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1500018/27535) setting:

```
...
WHERE DATENAME(month, MY_DATETIME) = 'August'
```

Comment: Maybe, there are no better solution for the problem as it's set, but this is the right way to Index Scan.

Comment: @Igor: the requirements for month only means a range check on date isn't feasible.  Could be a poor question though

Answer (score 1):

I use `EXTRACT` function instead of `DATEPART`. 
`DATEPART` function doesn't exist in my mysql.

Comment: This helped me! Extract works better because those accepted functions are not recognized in MYSQL here..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE A
WHERE DATENAME(MONTH, MY_DATETIME) = 'August'
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), My Date, 23) like '2020-10-%'