# SQL language dependent conversion (number to month name)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, localization

I would like to convert number to month name, language dependent. For example:

- 1 = **januari** in indonesia language
- 1 = **一月** in chinese language.
- 1 = **gennaio** in italian language.

How to do that? My purpose is to convert to my country language which is BAHASA MALAYSIA (JANUARI , FEBRUARI , MAC ... disember).

Comment: i  have an idea which is if month=1 then set monthname = 'Januari' else if month =2 then set monthname = 'Februari' . but i feel this is the bad idea. so any guys have better idea on it ?? thx

Comment: What's your programming language ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't localise in SQL Server in this fashion: you can use one language per query
This language setting is what DATENAME uses

So unless you want a huge number of lookup tables (one per language), then do this on the client.

DATENAME is also unreliable for some languages. See [DATENAME(MONTH,GETADATE()) is returning numeric value of the month as '09'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497952/datenamemonth-getadate-is-returning-numeric-value-of-the-month-as-09/1500018#1500018)

SQL Server 2012 adds some culture setting via FORMAT but you'd have to pass this into SQL Server. Like I said, do this in the client.

Edit:

Indonesian isn't supported in SQL Server 2005 via SET LANGUAGE.

So, for this **one** language you'd need a CASE

```
CASE DATEPART(month, GETDATE())
  WHEN 1 THEN 'januari '
  WHEN 2 THEN '...'
  ...
END
```

Otherwise, SET LANGUAGE or **do it in the client**

Comment: i think got mislead for my question, if i just wan display january as januari in indonesia language?

Comment: @ElynnChia: you mentioned Italian just now... answer updated anyway

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, localization shouldn't be done on server/business logic level if you can avoid it. Therefore, I would return the date/month in the stored procedure as a `DATETIME` or `INT` and localize this information in the client which handles the data.

Comment: i think got mislead for my question, if i just wan display january as januari in indonesia language?

Comment: @Elynn: Please describe where you want to display the localized month name. What's your client invoking that SP?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write it correctly for your kind of database. The main idea is:

```
result = to_char(date, MM)
result = REPLACE('1', "JANUARI", result)
result = REPLACE('2', "FEBRUARI", result)
....
```

And at least in Oracle it can be written without stored procedures